# Should we lower reputation requirement for comments?

Tags: feature-request

I'm running into a chicken/egg problem in this community. I often need to leave comments to get more details to answer questions, but I don't have enough reputation points to leave comments.

Is anybody else experiencing this problem?

Should we consider lowering the requirement to leave comments, at least until we have more active users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally tend to agree that the reputation requirements are a little mis-tuned and you get into some chicken-and-egg problems like you mention. I think the rules are the same as for StackOverflow, where I imagine it's easier to get rep, so is correctly tuned. I am not sure if they can or will be modified on a site-by-site basis.

I do try to regularly vote up all helpful answers I find when reading through the site to help kick-start reputation for new users and compensate for low usage in early days.

Comment: I've been spending time upvoting good questions and answers. Hopefully others will do the same so we can grow the user base.